Szekeres example 1.5 errata?
In Peter Szekeres's text "A Course in Modern Mathematical Physics", example 1.5 (dealing with partial orders) says:
The power set $2^S$ of a set $S$ is partially ordered by the relation of set inclusion $\subseteq$,
$$
\begin{align}
  & U \subseteq U \text{ for all } U \in S,\\
  & U \subseteq V \text{ and } V \subseteq W \implies U \subseteq W,\\
  & U \subseteq V \text{ and } V \subseteq U \implies U = V.
\end{align}
$$
But, shouldn't the first line read $U \subseteq U \text{ for all } U \in 2^S$ (or, $U \subseteq U \text{ for all } U \subseteq S$). That is, shouldn't $U$, $V$, and $W$ designate elements of the power set, not the set itself?

Yes, you are correct.
